# Converting to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dictionary

I have a row which looks like this:

```
{0: '{"Paradigms":["Agile Software Development","Scrum","DevOps","Serverless Architecture"],"Platforms":["Kubernetes","Linux","Windows","Eclipse","PagerDuty","Apache2","Docker","AWS EC2","Amazon Web Services (AWS)","Sysdig","Apache Kafka","AWS Lambda","Azure","OpenStack"],"Storage":["AWS S3","MongoDB","Cassandra","MySQL","PostgreSQL","AWS DynamoDB","Spring Data MongoDB","AWS RDS","MySQL/MariaDB","Datadog","Memcached"],"Languages":["Java","PHP","SQL","Bash","Perl","JavaScript","Python","C#","Go"],"Frameworks":["Ruby on Rails (RoR)","AWS HA",".NET","Serverless Framework","Selenium","CodeIgniter","Express.js"],"Other":["Cisco","Content Delivery Networks (CDN)","Kubernetes Operations (Kops)","Prometheus","VMware ESXi","Bash Scripting","Scrum Master","Infrastructure as Code","Performance Tuning","Serverless","System Administration","Linux System Administration","Code Review"],"Libraries/APIs":["Node.js","Jenkins Pipeline","jQuery","React","Selenium Grid"],"Tools":["Jenkins","Bitbucket","GitHub","AWS ECS","AWS IAM","Amazon CloudFront CDN","Terraform","AWS CloudFormation","Git Flow","Artifactory","Nginx","Grafana","Zabbix","Docker Compose","AWS CLI","AWS ECR","Chef","Jira","Git","Postfix","MongoDB Shell","Wowza","Amazon SQS","AWS SES","Subversion (SVN)","TeamCity","Microsoft Visual Studio","Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE)","VMware ESX","Fluentd","Sumo Logic","Slack","Apache ZooKeeper","AWS Fargate","Ansible","ELK (Elastic Stack)","Microsoft Team Foundation Server","Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)"]}',
 1: '{"Platforms":["Debian Linux","Windows","Linux","NetBeans"],"Storage":["MySQL","Morphia","MongoDB","Oracle SQL","PostgreSQL","IBM DB2"],"Languages":["HTML5","CSS","Java","JavaScript","C++","Less","XPath","PHP","R","XSLT","XUL"],"Frameworks":["GWT","JUnit","Hibernate","AngularJS","JavaServer Pages (JSP)","Spring","JNI","Selenium","ASP.NET","Apache Velocity"],"Other":["Ajax","COM"],"Libraries/APIs":["HTML5 Canvas","Digester","JAXB","Java Servlets","Node.js","Jackson","JDBC","Standard Template Library (STL)","FFTW","ODBC","OpenGL","XStream"],"Tools":["Subversion (SVN)","Apache Ant","Mime4J","YourKit","IntelliJ IDEA","Apache Tomcat","Git","GCC","Cygwin","Maven","Eclipse IDE","UJAC","Flash","Mathematica","Perforce","CVS","GDB","Grunt","JDeveloper"]}',
 2: '{"Platforms":["Firebase","XAMPP"],"Storage":["JSON"],"Languages":["CSS","Sass","JavaScript","TypeScript","HTML5","CSS3"],"Frameworks":["Angular","Bootstrap 3+","Jasmine"],"Libraries/APIs":["jQuery","Pure CSS"],"Tools":["Git","NPM","GitHub","Atom","Angular CLI","Photoshop CS5","Karma"]}',
 3: '{"Paradigms":["Agile","CQRS","Azure DevOps"],"Platforms":["Debian Linux","Windows","Azure","Red Hat Linux","Visual Studio Code","Docker"],"Storage":["PostgreSQL","SQL Server 2016"],"Languages":["Python","JavaScript","C#","SQL","Java","C","C++","Bash","HTML"],"Frameworks":["AngularJS",".NET","Qt","Ruby on Rails (RoR)","Hibernate","Spring",".NET Core"],"Other":["IIS","Google Material Design","EDA","Sagas","Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS)"],"Libraries/APIs":["jQuery","Ruby on Rails API"],"Tools":["Microsoft Visual Studio","Qt Creator","Mercurial","Git","Jira","Terraform","Jenkins","Atom","Vim Text Editor","Eclipse IDE","Maven","SonarQube","Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)"]}',
```

How would I convert this so that each key (Paradigms, Platforms, etc.) becomes a column in a pandas dataframe? I've already tried a few things...

Am pretty stuck so would really appreciate some help!:)

Expected output would be something like this, but with additional columns for additional keys after Paradigms (like Storage, Tools, Languages, etc.):

```
Paradigms Platforms Storage Languages ...
    0        0        0        0
    1        1        1        1
    2        2        2        2
    3        3        3        3
    4        4        4        4
```

this is the value of talentpool_subset['skills'][0] (which is the same as talentpool_df, just a subset of the bigger dataframe):

`````
'{"Paradigms":["Agile Software Development","Scrum","DevOps","Serverless Architecture"],"Platforms":["Kubernetes","Linux","Windows","Eclipse","PagerDuty","Apache2","Docker","AWS EC2","Amazon Web Services (AWS)","Sysdig","Apache Kafka","AWS Lambda","Azure","OpenStack"],"Storage":["AWS S3","MongoDB","Cassandra","MySQL","PostgreSQL","AWS DynamoDB","Spring Data MongoDB","AWS RDS","MySQL/MariaDB","Datadog","Memcached"],"Languages":["Java","PHP","SQL","Bash","Perl","JavaScript","Python","C#","Go"],"Frameworks":["Ruby on Rails (RoR)","AWS HA",".NET","Serverless Framework","Selenium","CodeIgniter","Express.js"],"Other":["Cisco","Content Delivery Networks (CDN)","Kubernetes Operations (Kops)","Prometheus","VMware ESXi","Bash Scripting","Scrum Master","Infrastructure as Code","Performance Tuning","Serverless","System Administration","Linux System Administration","Code Review"],"Libraries/APIs":["Node.js","Jenkins Pipeline","jQuery","React","Selenium Grid"],"Tools":["Jenkins","Bitbucket","GitHub","AWS ECS","AWS IAM","Amazon CloudFront CDN","Terraform","AWS CloudFormation","Git Flow","Artifactory","Nginx","Grafana","Zabbix","Docker Compose","AWS CLI","AWS ECR","Chef","Jira","Git","Postfix","MongoDB Shell","Wowza","Amazon SQS","AWS SES","Subversion (SVN)","TeamCity","Microsoft Visual Studio","Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE)","VMware ESX","Fluentd","Sumo Logic","Slack","Apache ZooKeeper","AWS Fargate","Ansible","ELK (Elastic Stack)","Microsoft Team Foundation Server","Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)"]}'````
`````

Comment: Can you please show your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment yet, here's what I've come up with. From what I understand "Paradigms, Platforms, etc" will be column names and the values will become rows.

Assign your row above as dictionary (dict). Get only the values to create list, then create a dataframe from that list.

```
import json
data = [ json.loads(v) for v in dict.values()]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes! That's what I was hoping to do. This is what I did:
````
v = talentpool_subset['skills'].to_dict()

import json
data = [json.loads(v) for v in dict.values()]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
````
And I got this error: "descriptor 'values' of 'dict' object needs an argument"

Comment: So I've made some progress with this code: data = [json.loads(row) for row in str(talentpool_df['skills'][0])] –
But am now running into this error:
"JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)" - any ideas on how to handle?

Comment: what is the value of this `talentpool_df['skills'][0])` ? Since you're treating that value as json string, you have to make sure that it is in json format if not `JSONDecodeError` will show up.

Comment: I've added talentpool_subset['skills'][0] to the original question as the entire value was too many characters for a comment. I'm fairly sure this is JSON but let me know if I'm wrong!